# Not able to add servers to graphite server

Tags: graphite

I want to know how to add clients to graphite server. I want to get logs of multiple servers in my graphite server.I have setup graphite server with gui,whisper and carbon on a centos 6.5 64 bit server.But now I want to know that how to add my  remote production servers to graphite to monitor the activities.

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? Have you read the [documentation](https://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)? Have you read [How to ask better questions on Serverfault](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3608/how-can-i-ask-better-questions-on-server-fault)?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Graphite automatically creates metrics as soon as you send it data. Try `echo foo.bar 5 \`date +%s\` | nc graphite.example.com 2003`.

Comment: I have setup graphite on centos 6.5 64 bit server. I am able to login to web console. Now I want to know how to add my servers to send logs to that graphite server. I tried to install collectd and collectl  on one linux server and I wrote the ip of graphite server in collectd and collectl conf files but still I am not able to see that server logs in graphite. I checked firewall and selinux also both are not running. Can you please provide me a good doc so that I can add all my servers to graphite server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send metrics to graphite. Two popular ones are

https://collectd.org/

and

https://github.com/BrightcoveOS/Diamond

Both of these run on each server you want to have in graphite and send system metrics to it.